# Missing SharePoint Server Publishing Feature on a Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise edition site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing, infrastructure, office

I have a licensed Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise edition and Office 2010 standard. In my project, I have a document library for which I would like to enable approve/reject and publish/unpublish features for the documents. I am able to activate approve/reject feature from version settings,but i am unable to activate the publish/unpublish feature .

I tried these commands

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishing\feature.xml -url "http://sp2010/sites/TestSiteCol/" -force

stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishingresources\feature.xml -url "http://sp2010/sites/TestSiteCol/" -force

stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishingSite\feature.xml -url "http://sp2010/sites/TestSiteCol/" -force

stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishingweb\feature.xml -url "http://sp2010/sites/TestSiteCol/" -force

stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishinglayouts\feature.xml -url "http://sp2010/sites/TestSiteCol/" -force

stsadm -o activatefeature -filename navigation\feature.xml -url "http://sp2010/sites/TestSiteCol/" -force

stsadm -o activatefeature -name PublishingResources -url "http://sp2010/sites/TestSiteCol/"

stsadm -o installfeature -name "http://sp2010/sites/TestSiteCol/"
```

Every command shows successfully activated, but i am unable to see "Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature in

> Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Site
>   Collection Features

in my top level site collection settings.

Are there any settings to activate the publishing feature in my site collection?

Comment: Have you tried PowerShell? Enable-SPFeature -Identity "PublishingSite" -Url "http://webapp/sitecollection" for the site collection feature and then Enable-SPFeature -Identity "PublishingWeb" -Url "http://webapp/sitecollection" for the site feature (assuming you want publishing in the root of your site collection)?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer.
my mistake is i chosen

document library settings >  Versioning settings > Document Version History > Create major versions.

but the solution is

after activating the above features in document library settings >  Versioning settings > Document Version History >  we have to choose "Create major and minor (draft) versions".

then only publishing button will enable.

Comment: You can mark your own reply as answer to finalize this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Run iisreset after the command.

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -name PublishingWeb -url https://<site>
iisreset
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Enterprise Features are Active in Central Administration.